# Preenchendo uma lista usando seu tamanho como critério de parada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando um código que define uma função que depende de duas variáveis (`Z` e `N`).

Esse programa define a soma dessas variáveis e anexa cada possível soma
em uma lista vazia.

A lista deverá ter 118 elementos, para isso criei uma lista vazia e estou anexando os valores da soma na lista um por vez, o programa rodará 118 vezes até a lista chegar no tamanho mencionado.

Porém não estou conseguindo compilar este código aqui, alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

```py
#Este programa cria uma classe chamada Número Atômico
class NumeroAtômico:

#Definindo a função Numero Atômico
    def A(Z,N):

    #Para isso, vamos completar a lista com todos os números atômicos
    # A lista que contem cada número atômico está aqui

        ListadeNumerosAtomicos=[]

        while len(ListadeNumerosAtomicos!=118):

            # O número de prótons Z é o número de prótons existentes no núcleo de um átomo
            print("")
            Z=int(input())

             # O número de neutrons N é o número de prótons existentes no núcleo de um átomo
            print("")
            N=int(input())

            # O número de massa A é a soma do número de prótons (Z) e de nêutrons (N) existentes num átomo

            A = Z + N


            if (A>=1) and (A<=118):
                print ("")
                print("")
                ListadeNumerosAtomicos.append(A)
                print(ListadeNumerosAtomicos)

            A(Z,N)
```

Comment: Note que o número atómico de um átomo (ou ião) é igual ao seu número de protões. O número de massa é a soma do número de protões com o número de neutrões (ou seja, é igual ao número de nucleões). A `ListadeNumerosAtomicos` deverá conter números atómicos e não números de massa. O número atómico é `Z` e o número de massa é `A`, no seu programa.

Comment: Parece que você está a tentar adicionar números de massa a uma lista que, supostamente, deveria conter números atómicos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Resposta geral:**

Use:

```py
for i in range(numero_de_elementos_que_a_sua_lista_deve_ter):
  funcoes_opcionais_que_alteram_o_elemento_a_adicionar()
  a_sua_lista.append(elemento_a_adicionar)
```

Veja a [documentação de `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) ou [`range` Python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=range+Python&t=hp&ia=web) para mais informações.

**Resposta específica:**

Note que o [número atómico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_at%C3%B3mico) de um [átomo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81tomo) (ou [ião](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8Don)) é igual ao seu número de [protões](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%B3ton), **sempre**. O [número de massa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_de_massa) é igual à soma do número de [protões](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%B3ton) com o número de [neutrões](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%AAutron) (ou seja, é igual ao número de [nucleões](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAcleon)).

No seu programa, você escreve `if (A>=1) and (A<=118):` e isto não permite obter os resultados esperados, porque nada diz que o número de massa `A` pertence ao [intervalo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalo_(matem%C3%A1tica)) [1, 118]. Parece que você está a confundir o número de massa com o número atómico... Aconselho-o seriamente a ver: [número atómico e número de massa](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=n%C3%BAmero+at%C3%B3mico+e+n%C3%BAmero+de+massa&t=hp&ia=web).

A `ListadeNumerosAtomicos` deverá conter números atómicos e não números de massa. O número atómico é `Z` e o número de massa é `A`, no seu programa.

Os números atómicos são sempre inteiros e, até agora, variam entre 1 e 118, inclusive. A lista de números atómicos dos [elementos conhecidos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_elementos_qu%C3%ADmicos#Listagem_tabelada) é igual a `list(range(1, 119))`, em Python. Parece que você está a tentar adicionar números de massa a uma lista chamada `ListadeNumerosAtomicos`. Será que você quer fazer uma lista de números de massa?

Experimente o seguinte, para obter uma lista de números de massa:

```py
def devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa():
  lista_de_numeros_de_massa = []
  for i in range(118):
    Z = int(input("Insira o número atómico: "))  # número de protões
    # O número atómico é o número de protões, SEMPRE!
    N = int(input("Insira o número de neutrões: "))  # número de neutrões
    lista_de_numeros_de_massa.append(N+Z)
  return lista_de_numeros_de_massa

print(devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa())
```

Ou, numa "linha":

```py
def devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa():
  return [int(input("Insira o número atómico: "))
          + int(input("Insira o número de neutrões: "))
          for i in range(118)]

print(devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa())
```

Se os elementos forem introduzidos por ordem crescente de número atómico: primeiro o hidrogénio, depois o hélio... só tem de escrever o seguinte:

```py
def devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa():
  lista_de_numeros_de_massa = []
  for Z in range(1, 119):
    N = int(input("Insira o número de neutrões do elemento com Z=%d: " % Z))
    lista_de_numeros_de_massa.append(N+Z)
  return lista_de_numeros_de_massa

print(devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa())
```

Ou, numa "linha":

```py
def devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa():
  return [int(input("Insira o número de neutrões do elemento com Z=%d:" % Z))
          + Z for Z in range(1, 119)]

print(devolve_lista_numeros_de_massa())
```